# Cannot test URL with PowerMockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

I've read some questions here with solutions that didn't work for me unfortunately.

I'm testing a Spring Boot application and I'm trying to mock a URL object in a test case with PowerMockito but it's not working for me, when I want to mock the `openConnection()` method, it throws me an `AbstractMethodError`.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at -(UrlExampleTest class)- 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

This would be the class:

```
public class UrlExample {

    public void callUrl() {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        HttpUrlConnection huc = url.openConnection(); 
        // ...
    }

}
```

And the test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ URL.class, URLConnection.class, HttpURLConnection.class, UrlExample.class }) // Other solutions suggested to specify all this but no success.
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UrlExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void mockUrl() {
        URL mockedUrl = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedUrl.openConnection()).thenReturn(httpURLConnection); // Exception thrown here
        // ...
    } 

}
```

I don't know what else to try, and I cannot change the original code to replace that URL object with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mocked the  URL constructor call.
Try This

```
@Test
public void mockUrl() {
    URL mockedUrl = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
    PowerMockito.when(mockedUrl.openConnection()).thenReturn(httpURLConnection); 
    PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockedUrl);// mocking constructor call.
}
```

Comment: I did, but I didn't iclude it here in the question because the exception is thrown before, in the line commented, with the mock itself in the test method.

Comment: PowerMockito.when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(httpURLConnection); // In this line  'url' should be 'mockedUrl' ?

Comment: Is that causing this error? It should be compile time error right?

Comment: I meant, it was mockedUrl in my original test case, it was an error writing the question here. Sorry for the confusion. I've corrected the question now. There's no compile time errors, but that `AbstractMethodError` thrown during runtime in the line I commented (`when()`).